# Search whole ebook in nov

Tags: search, grep

`nov.el` does not provide an easy function to search the whole of the ebook content. Every search performed on buffer only applies to the "document" or chapter of the book on display at that time.

The variable `nov-documents` returns an Alist of `(label . filepath)` cons cells where each document is located, previously unpacked to the `temp` folder for display purposes.

We can use `rgrep` on the parent directory of these documents to perform a search on the `xhtml` source files themselves.

```lisp
(setq docs nov-documents)
(setq path (file-name-directory (cdr (aref docs 1))))
(grep-compute-defaults)
(rgrep "empathy" "*xhtml" path)
```

Following the search links lead us, however, directly to the source files themselves and there is no easy way to get back to the `nov` buffer for regular reading.

Wonder if there is a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nov's own functionality to search the documents using the following command (obtained by inspecting nov.el's source):

```lisp
(defun nov-search (pattern)
  (interactive "sEnter search pattern: ")
  (let ((version nov-epub-version)
        (index 1)
        results)
    (while (< index (1- (length nov-documents)))
      (seq-let (id &rest path) (aref nov-documents index)
        (let (;; HACK: this should be looked up in the manifest
              (imagep (seq-find (lambda (item) (string-match-p (car item) path))
                                image-type-file-name-regexps))
              ;; NOTE: allows resolving image references correctly
              (default-directory (file-name-directory path)))
          (unless imagep
            (with-temp-buffer
              (if (and (version< version "3.0") (eq id nov-toc-id))
                  (insert (nov-ncx-to-html path))
                (insert (nov-slurp path)))
              (goto-char (point-min))
              (when (search-forward pattern nil t)
                (nov-render-html)
                (goto-char (point-min))
                (while (search-forward pattern nil t)
                  (push (list (format "%d %s" index
                                      (replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " "
                                                                (thing-at-point 'line)))
                              index (point))
                        results)))))
          (setq index (1+ index)))))
    ;; (print results)))
    (seq-let (index point) (alist-get (completing-read "Jump to: " (reverse results)) results
                                      nil nil #'string=)
      (nov-goto-document index)
      (goto-char point))))
```

Evaluate the code and do `M-x nov-search` from some epub buffer.

I have not tested it thoroughly, but this works on several EPUB's here. Also, this is just a quick solution, of course you are free to adapt it to your wishes.

Comment: Following the search result threw a `apply: Wrong type argument: fixnump, nil` error. Also, I wasn't able to step through the function with `edebug` to find out what's wrong, nor obtain any backtrace with `debug-on-error`

Comment: And the search function is super slow.

Comment: Okay, I have tested the function now on about 10 EPUB's, the search is fast (< 1 sec) on all of them, except for one where it crashes Emacs. So it looks like the search works for most epubs, but not for all of them. If you mean that you get the error after 'jumping' to the result, then I guess you can get slightly more info by printing the `alist-get` form. Unfortunately, this is hard to debug without having the 'recalcitrant' epub or a stack trace.

Comment: Try on [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0y88fxlbms580d/The%20Neurobehavioral%20and%20Social-Emotional%20D%20-%20Ed%20Tronick.epub?dl=0) ebook.

Comment: Searching works perfectly fine here, on that book. Which 'pattern' are you searching for (and, optionally, which result are you selecting)?

Comment: `(alist-get (completing-read "Jump to: " (reverse results)) results
                                      nil nil #'string=)` returns `nil` every time I pick a choice.

Comment: My search term is "empathy".

Comment: Ah okay. Searching for 'empathy' works perfectly fine here (returns 11 results), and the subsequent jumping to the match also. Also, edebug works perfectly fine on the function. Unfortunately, then, I am not sure what is going on there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141936/discussion-between-sati-and-dalanicolai).

Comment: I wrote my own [function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/282497/242934) based on your answer above.

Comment: I do not see any difference with my answer. Only that you kept out the check for the image, for which I corrected this answer, more or less at the same time that you commented, to include that check (see my edit, and its explanation).

Comment: I had to `(replace-regexp-in-string "\n" "" (thing-at-point 'sentence))` when compiling the search result to fix the problem. The search is still very slow, though. Took more than 10 seconds for the above search to complete.

Comment: I see now... but I think you should have tested my version with `emacs -q` first. As my answer worked here when using `emacs -q` on both Emacs versions 28.2 and 29. B.t.w the 'empathy' search takes 1 second here on my 'i5-5300' processor from 2015.